# Editing "Time to display recovery options when needed" timeout value using a program

Tags: batch-file, settimeout, boot

I want to edit the timeout value of `Time to display recovery options when needed` without using the UI display option.

To navigate, Right click on `Mycomputer` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced` tab -> click on SETTINGS of `Startup and recovery` => 2nd displayed check box.

The value thought to be in `c:\boot.ini` file, but it has value of other timeout `Time to display other operating systems`. After some searching,I found that `c:\windows\bootstat.dat` file holds the timeout value for `Time to display recovery options when needed`...

But, i am not able to decode the .dat file or edit that file.. any suggestions would he helpful for me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://gitlab.com/rhave/bootstat.dat-efi-parser
this does decode it, but no sure if you can edit

Answer (score -1):

use bcdedit:

```
bcdedit /timeout 123
```

Comment: That’s for “Time to display list of operating systems”, not “Time to display recovery options when needed”.

Comment: As Olivier pointed out, this is not the correct answer as it is a completely different setting.